# Call Web API protected by Azure AD from Xamarin Forms

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

I am hoping to find for a working sample or guidance that shows a Xamarin Forms application that authenticates against Azure AD and then uses a token to call a Web API that is secured by the same Azure AD.

Something like this but using Xamarin Forms:
http://timothelariviere.com/2017/02/13/call-an-azure-ad-protected-api-in-xamarinuwp-apps/

Comment: The example you link to has some info on how to do it with PCL and Xamarin.Forms: "If you’re making a PCL project, you’ll need to target the PCL Profile 7".

It even links to this blog post https://blog.xamarin.com/put-adal-xamarin-forms/ which is a PCL based Xamarin.Forms app that uses the ADAL NuGet package.

Comment: This is not a "find a working sample" service. SO is for solving small, reproducible programming problems.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides lots of code sample to integrate with Azure AD, and you can refer the link below which is developing with Xamarin Forms:

[Integrate Azure AD with Xamarin apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-xamarin)